# ID is not showing in Edit Form Action

Tags: php, cakephp

I am not able to see ID value in action of controller in Edit form. It is showing somthing like this..

```
<form action="/XXProj/userpages/edit" class="form-horizontal" id="UserpageEditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
```

and here is my Controller function..

```
 <?php error_reporting(0);
   class UserpagesController extends AppController {
     public $helpers = array("Html", "Form","Session");
       public $uses = array('Userpage','Usergroup');

public function index() {
}

    public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Userpage->id = $id;
    $this->set("userpages", $this->Userpage->read());
    pr($this->Userpage->read());
    if ($this->request->is("get")) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Userpage->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Userpage->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("updated.");
            $this->redirect(array("action" => "index"));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to update.");
        }
    }
}

public function delete($id = null) {
}
}
```

Can anybody has idea why it is not showing???

Comment: For one thing, take out `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That's only used for uploading and/or file attachments, unless that's your added intention.

Comment: Also, your html form uses POST, and you have `if ($this->request->is("get")) {` which could also pose a problem.

Comment: I removed file type but still no rsult.

Comment: And this `value="POST"` - am doubting that's what you mean. Like I said, I'm having trouble understanding the concept behind all this.

Comment: I will SAVE value in ELSE statement.

Comment: Why is error_reporting(0) set to disabled? That is the most stupid thing you can do. You can't see your own errors and it becomes hard to debug, that's like shooting your own feet. And I've seen clients suing their former cheap low level "developer" after we enabled error reporting on their site...

Comment: Don't use read(), use find(). There is your problem probably. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.